# Prediction failed on GCP ml engine

Tags: google-cloud-ml

Hi I have successfully deployed an object detection model on ml engine. However when I request for predictions it gives me the following error.

```
ERROR: (gcloud.ml-engine.predict) HTTP request failed. Response: {
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Request payload size exceeds the limit: 1572864 bytes.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

I use the following command:

```
gcloud ml-engine predict --model fastercnn --version v4 --json-instances input.json
```

My input.json looks like this :

```
{"inputs": {"b64": "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/..............}}
```

Note I have truncated the `long base 64` encoding of image for ease of readability.

My model definition :

MetaGraphDef with tag-set: 'serve' contains the following SignatureDefs:

```
signature_def['serving_default']:
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
    inputs['inputs'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_STRING
        shape: (-1)
        name: encoded_image_string_tensor:0
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
    outputs['detection_boxes'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (-1, 300, 4)
        name: detection_boxes:0
    outputs['detection_classes'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (-1, 300)
        name: detection_classes:0
    outputs['detection_features'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (-1, -1, -1, -1, -1)
        name: detection_features:0
    outputs['detection_multiclass_scores'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (-1, 300, 2)
        name: detection_multiclass_scores:0
    outputs['detection_scores'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (-1, 300)
        name: detection_scores:0
    outputs['num_detections'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (-1)
        name: num_detections:0
    outputs['raw_detection_boxes'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (-1, 300, 4)
        name: raw_detection_boxes:0
    outputs['raw_detection_scores'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (-1, 300, 2)
        name: raw_detection_scores:0
  Method name is: tensorflow/serving/predict
```

I tried to resize my image using the following code so it does not exceed the bytes but still gives me the same error :

```
import base64
from PIL import Image
width = 256
height = 256
import json
import io
instances = []

with open('input.json', 'w') as f:
    img = Image.open("test_image/hand1.jpg")
    img = img.resize((width, height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    output_str = io.BytesIO()
    img.save(output_str, "JPEG")
    image_byte_array = output_str.getvalue()
    image_base64 = base64.b64encode(image_byte_array).decode()
    json_entry = {'image_bytes': {"b64": image_base64}}
    request = json.dumps(json_entry)
    f.write(request)
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's complaining your json file is too large. They only allow 33554432 bytes.

Comment: but then how should I encode image to base 64 format like reducing image dimensions and then encoding it ?

Comment: The payload size limit is currently 1.5Mb. It's common to resize the image and re-encode it, e.g., as a JPEG on the client before sending over the wire. This may require some adaptations to the TF graph, e.g., if you're not already decoding JPEG.

Comment: @rhaertel80I have edited my question to include the resizing part.

Comment: ok I was able to generate predictions by reducing the image size to 128 x 128 dimension as JPEG on client and using cloud predict command it returned me the predictions

Comment: Glad to hear it. You can likely have a bigger image, e.g. 1024x1024 raw is only 1MB.